# while going through api/register url the following error occurs AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**urls.py file**

```
from .views import RegisterAPI , LoginAPI
from knox import views as knox_views
from django.urls import path
from accounts import views




urlpatterns = [
    path('' , views.index , name='home') ,
    path('register' , views.register , name='register') ,
    path('login' , views.login , name='login') ,
    path('logouts' , views.logouts , name='logouts') ,
    path('api/register/', RegisterAPI.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('api/login/', LoginAPI.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('api/logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('api/logoutall/', knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view(), name='logoutall'),
]
```

above file is my urls.py file in which i am getting error when i am trying api/register

Comment: Where do you exactly get this error? Could you share related views and the code?

Comment: brother i dont know why but here i am unable to paste my full code it is showing error

Comment: i have created a project  which is having custom user model .... my normal django is working fine but when i am trying to use api/register as url it shows the above error

Comment: i have created a manager.py file , serializer.py file  , custom user model , views .py file

Comment: tell me which file do you wantt ?